# How to fix shiny cuff from iron

Tags: clothing

For some reason my shirt has been ruined by  the following shiny patch on my cuff. Same can be seen on shirt back. First I do not understand why it happen and how to fix it?

Comment: If the heat of the iron was too hot, and has smoothed the shirt surface to create a shiny patch, your only solution is to buy a new shirt (or I suppose you could make the entire shirt shiny so it wouldn't show...)

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if I wash a shirt again, the shininess goes away. Then, when I iron, I turn the shirt inside out. That is, I iron the side of the shirt that would be touching my skin if I was wearing it. Then, if there is any shininess, it will only be on that side of the shirt that nobody can see.  The side that everybody sees looks normal.

Comment: I will try and report back.

Comment: Reporting Back. I washed them but shine is still there.

Comment: @Nofel Sorry. I thought that washing it would remove the shine.